# MacBook (late 2008) EFI Firmware Update 1.8 Problem

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, firmware

Last night I applied EFI Firmware update 1.8 to my Macbook (late 2008). After installing EFI Firmware Update and rebooted my computer and installed SuperDrive Firmware Update 3.0. After that my Macbook rebooted and a black screen is showing with "No bootable device. Please insert bootable device and press any key to continue". I put in one of the bootable installation disck (MAC OS) and it's still stuck on the same screen. I have also tried restarting my macbook manually but no luck.

Have anyone experienced that?

Answer (score 0):

Try holding down the option key on startup until you get a boot option. Hopefully your HD will be one of the boot options. Select the MacOS drive to boot. When you are back in, go to Preferences and select your HD as startup disk. Also try it with your OS X DVD in the drive.

If not, you may be able to use Target Disk mode (depending on the age of your MacBook) to get in to run Disk Utility and reset the boot disk: [How to use and troubleshoot FireWire target disk mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1661)

If not, try the Apple Forums [Apple - Support - Discussions - MacBook](http://discussions.apple.com/category.jspa?categoryID=218)

Answer (score 0):

I have also seen this problem and, as suggested, was able to fix it by booting off the OS X DVD by holding down "c" with the disc in the drive at startup.  Once the OS X Installer starts, quit it and then select the Mac Hard Drive as the boot device.

Answer (score 0):

I've found my way forward that was later confirmed by an Apple technician. I had the same black screen, inserted the OSX boot DVD, nothing happened, screen stayed black with that little note.

Here's the fix how it worked for me:

Press the on/off button until shutoff (I was first afraid to do so), then press it to on again with the <kbd>c</kbd> button pressed. Macbook will boot from DVD (Ignore the welcome window - on the top), open the Utilities - select the MacIntosh HD - have it boot from there. Afterwards, verify in the preferences/system/startup disk that the Macintosh HD is selected for startup.

This should be it. Then Log in. Still recommend staying connected to time capsule if you need your Mac for working, studying, etc.