# MacBook(late 2008) EFI Firmware Update 1.8 Problem

Tags: macbook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MacBook(late 2008) EFI Firmware Update 1.8 Problem](https://superuser.com/questions/81268/macbooklate-2008-efi-firmware-update-1-8-problem)

Last night I applied EFI Firmware update 1.8 to my Macbook(late 2008). After installing EFI Firmware Update and rebooted my computer and installed SuperDrive Firmware Update 3.0. After that my Macbook rebooted and a black screen is showing with "No bootable device. Please insert bootable device and press any key to continue". I put in one of the bootable installation disck (MAC OS) and it's still stuck on the same screen. I have also tried restarting my macbook manually but no luck.

Have anyone experienced that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Endless redirection going on between SO and SU....

Dup and possible answer here: [MacBook (late 2008) EFI Firmware Update 1.8 Problem](https://superuser.com/questions/81268/macbooklate-2008-efi-firmware-update-1-8-problem)